# How to set Notepad2 to use UTF-8 instead of ANSI

Tags: windows, utf-8, ansi, notepad2

Each time I create a new file in Notepad2, the encoding is ANSI (1252). 
I'd like instead to have UTF-8 as default. Is there a way to get this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
File → Encoding → Default... → UTF-8
```

If the change doesn't stick when you restart Notepad2 change the default again and then try :

```
Settings -> Save Settings Now
```

This is using Notepad2 v4.2.25

Comment: no encoding option in file menu

Comment: I have it in Notepad2 4.0.23, and it's been there since version 2.x.

Comment: Me too in 4.2.25

Comment: If you receive a permission error when saving settings (e.g. if you installed Notepad2 in place of Notepad.exe) then you need to run it as Administrator before performing these steps.

Comment: In `Notepad2.ini`, this corresponds to setting `DefaultEncoding=3`.
(Value 3 instead of 0.)

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings -> Preferences -> New Document, check UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: wrong!! for notepad++ you should NOT use `UTF-8 with signature` (BOM) **ever!** this is a mistake that could corrupt your source files (if you are a developer / programmer) and showing "weird icons" in your web-pages, and "you won't know why!" (because most of us won't turn on the "show all symbols").  for notepad2 it is "upside-down" there you should select `"UTF-8"` and not `UTF-8 with signature`!!!!

Comment: @EladKarako: Who says this is for Web use (in any case, no problem for IIS and most web servers on Windows)? In the Windows world, a BOM can be extremely useful for suitable applications to better understand the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Run notepad2.exe with a parameter. Example in command prompt or other program:

```
Notepad2.exe /utf8 MyAnsiiFile.txt
```

This opens and loads an ASCII file and converts it to a UTF-8 file.
Then, you need only to close Notepad2 and save.

notepad2 version 4.2.25