# How to set Notepad2 to use Unix newlines (LF) by default

Tags: windows, newlines, notepad2, crlf

Each time I create a new file in Notepad2, the default line break is
Windows-style: 
a carriage return (CR) followed by a line feed (LF). 
How can I instead set Unix-style line endings (LF) as default?

Answer (score 0):

*File → Line Endings → Default... → Unix (LF)*

[image: File → Line Endings → Default... → Unix (LF).]

Tested on Notepad2 version 4.2.25.

*Note!* In `Notepad2.ini`, this corresponds to having
`DefaultEOLMode=1` (typically line 40), 
while a fresh installation has `DefaultEOLMode=0` (CR+LF).

A related question is
[How to set Notepad2 to use UTF-8 instead of ANSI](https://superuser.com/q/80885), 
but that question is about default *character encoding* rather than
the default *newline type*.